# How to animate blur filter in Firefox?

Tags: css, css-animations

```
@-webkit-keyframes myBlur{
   from{
      -webkit-filter:blur(0px);
   }
   to{
      -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
   }
}
```

It seems "blur" is not implemented in Firefox and we could use svg filter instead. Is it possible to animate svg filter to achieve the same as above code?

Answer (score 2):

ATM you cant.

I tried in all the way, but animating (as with @keyframe or via transition) does not work neither with Aurora build.

Looking forward for it

Answer (score 1):

I got my firefox blurring here

http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur

the SVG blur works .. you might try an SVG animation ?

*-pike

Answer (score 0):

Try Foggy and then loop through and change the `blurRadius` and `Opacity`.

http://nbartlomiej.github.com/foggy/

Comment: It would be nice if you could expand this answer to demonstrate with some code how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter

You are using a webkit prefix which is for webkit browsers. I know a while back Mozilla announced they would support webkit prefixes but I don't know if this is one of them since its experimental.

```
// Browser Specific
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
```